# Interpret a string with escape characters from stdin

Tags: linux, shell

if I have a file like:

```
hello \n world
```

how can I print the contents of the file with the escape sequences interpreted, so in the terminal you see:

```
hello 
 world
```

I've tried `cat file | xargs -I{} echo {}` but that prints `hello n world`

Comment: Honestly, I'd fix the file. No standard text format actually uses those escapes to represent a newline; `\n` is the kind of thing a programming language uses to represent unprintable characters in a string literal.

Comment: Something like this probably: `echo 'a\nb' | while read -r var; do echo -e "$var"; done`.

Comment: @chepner how would you fix the file? replacing the escapes with caret notation?

Comment: Just put real newlines in the file. Without knowing the source or why it includes such digraphs, I don't have any better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```sh
echo 'hello\\nworld' | xargs -I {} printf "%b" "{}"
```

is what you're after. But that requires you to have some control over the text sent over the pipe since it requires double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

`printf`'s `%b` format specifier expands escape sequences:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(cat file)"
hello
 world
```

To read from stdin an unadorned `cat` will do:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(cat)"
hello
 world
```

Comment: I think I made a mistake wording the question. What I actually want is to expand escape sequences from a string coming from stdin. The example with the file is how I conceptualezed it moving to stdin, but I should change that to depend on stdin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying but its really hard to word it correctly. I'll try tomorrow